# SharePoint CSOM filenotfound exception

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have developed a SharePoint Client object model using c#.net. I want to run the executable in other servers where sharePoint is not installed. How can i bundle the SharePoint Client dll's into my Executable so that i need not to install the Client SDK on to the server where i want to run this exe. Is there any way without using any tool? Please suggest